# Sorting Polymorphic Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, polymorphism

Lets say I have 3 classes (Passenger,Pilot,Stewardess) that inherit from an abstract class called Persons, and in an array of Persons I save up many of these objects from the 3 classes already defined, but then I want to sort those objects inside the array of Persons in the following order:

-All the objects from class Passenger

-All the objects from class Pilot

-All the objects from class Stewardess

Is there any way to achieve this without ArrayLists?

Comment: Persons implements Comparable<Persons>?

Comment: C.f. [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List))

Comment: Why without an ArrayList? Show what you have tried, it will be easier to understand what you're having difficulty with

Answer (score 2):

```
Arrays.sort(personArray, new Comparator<Person>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        int person1Index = getOrderIndex(p1);
        int person2Index = getOrderIndex(p2);

        if (person1Index < person2Index) {
            return -1;
        } else if (person1Index > person2Index) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private int getOrderIndex(Person p) {
        if (p == null) {
            return 0;
        } else if (p instanceof Passenger) {
            return 1;
        } else if (p instanceof Pilot) {
            return 2;
        } else if (p instanceof Stewardess) {
            return 3;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected person type: " + p.getClass().getName());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to sort an array of Objects, which inherit from Person, by type.  Yes, this can be done.

```
Person[] people = new Person[]; //this creates a new array of Person's
```

There are a number of different techniques you can use to sort this array, but you will need to be able to identify the specific type of each Person.  This can be achieved using reflection:

```
for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  String s = people[i].getClass().getSimpleName();
  //do whatever you need to do
}
```

Another way to do it, which was suggested in a comment on the original post, and which I think is superior if you are bubble sorting 3 types, is the following:

Have Person implement the Comparable interface.  Then, implement the compareTo method within each subclass like so:

**Edit:** Style edit.  We want this particular comparison only to apply to `Person`s and not `Object`s in general.

```
class Pilot extends Person {
  public int compareTo(Person o) {
    if (o instanceof Passenger)
        return 1;
    else if (o instanceof Stewardess)
        return -1;
    return 0;
  }
}

class Passenger extends Person {
  public int compareTo(Person o) {
    if (o instanceof Passenger)
      return 0; //if the two objects are equal from the perspective
                //of our comparison, it is proper form to return 0
    return -1;
  }
}

class Stewardess extends Person {
  public int compareTo(Person o) {
    if (o instanceof Stewardess)
      return 0;
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Now, even though you have three classes, you can directly compare any two objects and get a value usable for sorting (<0 goes left, >0 goes right).

**Edit:** Clarification (not enough room in comments)

The `compareTo()` method is exactly as simple as it looks.  There is no magic going on behind the scenes.  What it is doing is providing a level of indirection, allowing us to compare objects of different types as if they were the same.  In the case of sorting objects in a collection (at the comparison level) we do not care about the type, or any other information about the properties of the objects.  We only need to know whether object A should come before, or after object B.  The `compareTo()` method serves as a custom comparison operation that we can apply to any `Person` object which will tell us whether that object should precede or succeed the object it is being compared to, and nothing else.  `Passenger.compareTo()` will always return -1 because `Passenger` will come before every other type.  The opposite is true of `Stewardess`.

*Please note I have edited the code for the sake of proper style.

Comment: I tried with instanceof with a bubblesort method and yeah it sorts it perfectly if for 2 classes inherited from the abstract class, but when is > 2 classes it doesn't seems like the proper way to do it. I edited the post so you can understand what I meant! thanks for your time

Comment: Yeah, I was suggesting that instanceof is probably not the best way to do it.  try the example I gave.

Comment: That's awesome! it worked, but I don't really get how's that working I mean what's going on behind the compareTo method? why are you returning the opposite values in both pilot and stewardess classes?